# jquery-ui-tabs copies the entire website 

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

Link: http://www.dynamicweb.dk/Versioner-33012.aspx
Whenever I activate my tabs, the entire website gets copied into the content for the specific tab.

Any suggestions why ?

Click 'se tillægsmoduler' to see the problem.

Comment: I couldn't find any 'se tillægsmoduler' occurrence on you website. Is your issue still there?